# Symfony 3.4 assets:install fails via SSH

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I’m using two different deployment libs to deploy my Symfony 3.4 application.

Both SSH into the server, pull from a repo and then set up my application. One of the steps is assets:install and the next is cache:warmup

If the deployment script SSHs into the server then assets install fails. With no error. If I stop the process before the deployment does this step then SSH myself in and then run the same command to asset install it works.

If asset install is taken out of the process. Cache warmup is next and that then fails with no error. But again if I stop the process and SSH in it works.

This is very odd and I cannot find any error logs that help me.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem might be the deployment script, not the symfony or php itself.
I.e deploy script may actually be in another dir than you when logging with the SSH. I'd add `pwd` command to the deployment script so you know where you are and when deploy script gets onto the server, then check from there.

Answer (score 0):

The target server did not have APCU installed. Adding that fixed the issue.